# Python MLPClassifier Value Error

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, artificial-intelligence

I'm currently trying to train the MLPClassifier implemented in sklearn...
When i try to train it with the given values i get this error:

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

The format of the feature_vector is

[ [one_hot_encoded brandname], [different apps scaled to mean 0 and variance 1] ]

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong ?

Thank you!

feature_vectors:

[

array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]),

array([ 0.82211852, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818,  4.45590895, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818,  0.3439882 , -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
        4.93403927, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,  0.63086639,
        1.10899671, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,  1.58712703, -0.22976818,
        1.77837916, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818,  2.16088342, -0.22976818,  2.16088342,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,  9.42846428, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
        0.91774459, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,  4.16903076, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,  2.44776161,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,  1.96963129,  1.96963129,
        1.96963129, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,  7.13343874,
        5.98592598, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
        3.02151799,  4.26465682, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818,  2.25650948, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
        1.30024884, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,  4.74278714, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,  0.3439882 ,
       -0.22976818,  0.3439882 , -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818,  0.53524033, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818,  3.49964831,
       -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818, -0.22976818])

]

g_a_group:

[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]

MLP:

from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

clf = MLPClassifier(solver='lbfgs', alpha=1e-5,
                   hidden_layer_sizes=(5, 2), random_state=1)

clf.fit(feature_vectors, g_a_group)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data does not make any sense from scikit-learn perspective of what is expected in the `.fit` call. Feature vectors is supposed to be a matrix of size `N x d`, where `N` - number of **data points** and `d` number of **features**, and your second variable should hold labels, thus it should be vector of length `N` (or `N x k` where `k` is number of outputs/labels per point). Whatever is represented in your variables - their sizes do not match what they should represent.

Comment: Hmm, i don't really understand, why my feature vector isn't right.
This is just 1 of the 16k samples...
My feature vector consist of a brand name, encoded in one-hot and an array with different counts (in this example how many times an app is used).
Which means i have 2 features... the brand name and the apps. This is one sample.

The second variable holds a gender-age-group also one-hot encoded, since i can't pass a String to the MLPClassifier. In this case it's the associated group for the feature vector...

Comment: Can't i use an array as a feature ? 
Could you give me a valid example (not the one in the documentation) of a feature vector and a label please ?

Comment: @Tim.G. A feature is one column of some array (of column-size **d**). Why another example which is not part of the docs. These examples are perfectly suited to understand the concept.

Comment: I got it working... MLPClassifier can't handle nested arrays, just a one dimensional.
Because the example in the docs is extremely minimalistic... Why would if have only 1 single feature with 2 values ? 
I couldn't quickly figure out how to take such big arrays and learn my MLP with them, a documentation should give more than one super simple example.

But thank you for your time.

Comment: you simply use different meaning of "feature" which **is not** classical meaning of this word in the community of linear model (or pretty much any part of ML besides decision trees and inductive logic). Typically in machine learning, feature is not "a property of the object being described" where you can put this property to be an arbitrary object, but rather it is considered a **single scalar value**, thus if you have one hot encoding this actually generates new features, it does not really create "values" for the features. Using this language, example with 2 features is as generic as needed.